# Python Regex, calling a variable before it is defined?

Tags: python, regex

I am confused as to how this code actually works:

```
print([m.start() for m in re.finditer('p', word)])
```

If I were to just run the `print` statement without the `for` loop, but leaving everything else, m isn't defined. How can I run a `for` loop after the `m.start()` method is called, and create the variable in the `for` loop? If anybody could just break down this code and explain what is actually happening I would be really appreciative.

Comment: It's a list comprehension. See [python.org#list-comprehensions](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions)

Comment: To be honest folks I do not understand this website. I ask a valid question, specific enough to where there isn't an answer. I am not good enough at code to understand the regex site, and I figured it would take a skilled coder maybe 2 minutes to answer this. Can somebody explain why this is being downvoted? Is it against the culture to ask such nooby questions? Truly don't get it.

Comment: @khelwood thank you very much. After reading that I figure it is that I don't understand the start method of regex, which is why it confused me so much. I appreciate it.

Comment: Because you aren't running a for-loop. This is a list-comprehension, and isn't related to the regex methods at all.

Comment: I really recommend reading [this](https://treyhunner.com/2015/12/python-list-comprehensions-now-in-color/) website, as it has a great explanation about list comprehensions, which will help you to understand how they work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the same code, written without the use of a [generator expression](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0289/) (that one-liner for loop)

```
result_list = []
for m in re.finditer('p', word):
    result_list.append(m.start())
print(result_list)
```

That's pretty straight forward, so let's get into how we're representing that in your code snippet.

`re.finditer('p', word)` returns an iterable we're going to loop over.

`m.start() for m in re.finditer('p', word)` is the generator expression. Think of it as saying "The value returned by `m.start()` for each of the items `m` in the iterable returned by `re.finditer('p', word)`". Don't get caught up on the fact we use `m` before reading it - that's just Python's syntax being natural language inspired rather than operation-oriented.

`[m.start() for m in re.finditer('p', word)]` iterates the generator we defined, putting the values into a list. A common mistake is assuming that we can treat the generator as a list - it can't be indexed and can only be iterated once.

Hope that helps!

Comment: It's a list comprehension, not a generator expression being put into a list.